# How to read a file from bash argument

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I am trying to read a file into array `wordsarr`.
This works:

**myscript.sh**

```
mapfile -t wordsarr < words.txt
```

But I want to read it from argument specified. So I tried following:

```
mapfile -t cussWords < $1
```

It gave me following error:

```
 >>./myscript.sh words.txt
 4r5e
```

So I changed it to following: `mapfile -t cussWords < "$1"`, but it still gave me same error.
So I changed it to following: `mapfile -t cussWords < '$1'`. Then ended up getting following error:

```
./myscript.sh: line 1: $1: No such file or directory
```

Am quite new to bash and seems that I miss some basics here.

[Here](https://repl.it/@RanjanMaria/mapfilefromarg) you can see it in action:

[image]

Comment: Please show your script's shebang and check your words.txt file is in your current directory. Then see how to debug a shell script with `-xv` options.

Comment: @LéaGris added online runnable file at the end of question

Comment: `mapfile -t cussWords < "$1"` *should* work, provided you're using bash v4 or later (and not some other shell). And " 4r5e" doesn't look like an error. I think something else is going on, but without an example showing this problem, it's hard to say what.

Answer (score 0):

Use `cat`:

```sh
cat "$1" | mapfile -t cussWords
```

Comment: tried doing `echo ${cussWords[@]}` next.  It did not output anything.

Comment: The right side of the pipe is a sub-shell. So it won't assign cussWords to the main shell. And cat is totally useless here.

Comment: added online runnable file at the end of question